# uploadify to upload more than 1000 photo

Tags: php, uploadify, image-uploading

I need to upload more than 10000 images togather for a project in php. After changing max_file_uploads to 1000 in php.ini i can only upload 200 photos at a time.now i'm using uplodify but it allows only 999 files to be uploaded at a time.how can increase this limit to 2000?here's my code in the index page`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploadLimit' : 2000,
'formData'     : {
'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
},
'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can uploading files with using File API (HTML5) and creat queue with files with some count files?
I think that this is real.
This is my code. Quick wrote. You can change it by yourself.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<form onSubmit="upload_files(this); return false;">
  <input type="file" name="files_upload" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<script>
var tests = {
              filereader: typeof FileReader !== 'undefined',
              formdata: !!window.FormData
            };
var limit = 199; // Limit files in queue.

function upload_files(form) {
  var files = form.elements.files_upload.files;
  var files_length = files.length;
  var files_count = 0;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formdata = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i < files_length; i++) {
    if ((files_count < (limit - 1))) {
      formdata.append('files[' + i + ']', files[i]);
      files_count++;
    }
    else {
      files_count = 0;
      formdata.append('files[' + i + ']', files[i]);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'uploader.php');
      xhr.send(formdata);
      var formdata = new FormData();
    }
  }
  if (files_count < limit && files_count > 0) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'uploader.php');
    xhr.send(formdata);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to ask questions, use comments. If you want to post answer it should be complete, with your code in answer's body, not external attachement.